# Using a small Li-Po as a backup power source for a model

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo

I am building a model of a trolleytruck (similar to a trolleybus but with a truck) and I'm adding an Arduino to get data. The microcontroller should never lose power because it would restart. I was planning to add a small Li-po battery to supply power to the microcontroller when the truck is not getting power from the lines (in case of some oxide forming on the wires or anything else).

Both the Arduino and the motor can be powered with 3.7v, so a 1S battery would be ok.

Is there anything that I can buy that manages the charging and discharging of the battery? Will the battery get damaged because of those quick intermitent charges and discharges?

Thanks for all and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It might be better to use 4V lead acid, or 3.6V NiMH, these will be easier to charge, and to protect against overcharge. Otherwise if you insist on LiPo, then consult the catalogues of people like Maxim, TI and the other suppliers for dedicated charging ICs. No specific part numbers are appropriate to give in answer, it's against the policy of the site as they will be out of date next year. Quick intermittent charge and discharge, no problem, overcharge and overdischarge, big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get your trolley power to 5V with a buck regulator module or whatever, you can use a USB-powered LiPo charging module to charge the battery.

Chinese modules based on the [TP4056](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) from NanJing Top Power are popular at the moment.

However, powering the motors and the Arduino from the same supply may cause issues with start-up surges. You could consider a relatively large reservoir capacitor and Schottky diode to isolate the Arduino from momentary drops in the battery voltage.